# change svn working copy to another directory

Tags: macos, svn

Q: So I have local svn setup on my mac. I want to change to working copy of a repository to another folder without 'svn checkout', so that I can commit some code that is not currently in the working copy.

Problem with 'svn checkout'
The reason I don't want to use 'svn checkout' is b/c I don't want to overwrite the code into the new folder designated for working copy, because when I move the new code into the new designated folder and do an svn commit, I get an error based on the .svn hidden folders that svn attaches to your committed code.

What I am trying to accomplish?
I got myself into this mess, b/c I am trying to add multiple versions of my code into different folders, so that I can compare them against one another.

Thanks, Jon

Comment: I think you are not using svn appropiately. 0. As far as i know you can't have a working copy without a checkout. 1. For starters upgrade to svn 1.7 if you can, it reduces the `.svn` hidden folders to only one for each working copy. 2. If you really need different versions of your code then maybe look into branches, it might be a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a svn checkout, it does not delete and overwrite existing files - it merges them (try it - make a backup copy of your target directory and then svn checkout into it).

However, the simplest way is to svn checkout into a clean directory, then copy your files on top of the checkout. Rename your current directory to something else if you need to keep the directory name for your checkout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "svn copy" to copy one or more files in a working copy or in the repository.
More details: http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/copy/

I hope it helps.

Comment: At this point, I don't think there is a way to change working copy without svn checkout. But the gbjbaanb has said to do the svn checkout, and then on updates do a mf (for mine-full). Think this should work.

Comment: unneeded added files will be added, but merges you can revert to self code